# PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 12, 32768 bytes)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, redhat

Reading a server boot sequence of a redhat server 5.8, i saw this and for me is very unclear, maybe i wrong, but i know the linux kernel body allocator uses a power of two mechanism for allocate and dellocate the system memory,

From boot messagges:

```
 PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 12, 32768 bytes)
 Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
 Dentry cache hash table entries: 33554432 (order: 16, 268435456 bytes)
 Inode-cache hash table entries: 16777216 (order: 15, 134217728 bytes)
```

Order in power of two

```
 python -c 'import math ; print int(math.pow(2,12))*4096'
 16777216
 python -c 'import math ; print int(math.pow(2,16))*4096'
 268435456
 python -c 'import math ; print int(math.pow(2,15))*4096'
 134217728
```

So, my question is, Why the first line "PID hash table entrie" isn't 16777216 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PID hash table entries allocated as 2^N `struct hlist_head`s, which on a 64bit system are 8 bytes each. `2^12*8 = 32768`.

Inode/Dentry caches are allocated as 2^N pages, usually 4096 bytes each. `2^15*4096 = 134217728`.

This info is available in the source, `kernel/pid.c` and `fs/inode.c` respectively.